# On change of a selected value show an input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to choose yes value in this dropdown, so I can show another input field to add discount.

I am trying but nothing is showing. Can you please help me?

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">

  <select class="form-control m-input" name="is_offer" id="is_offer" onclick="myFunction()" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected >--Choose--</option>
  <option value="yes" >Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div id="offer"></div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('is_offer').value = 'yes') {
      document.getElementById('offer').innerText = '<div class="form-group m-form__group row"> <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">* Discount::</label> <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9"> <div id="asd"></div> </div> </div>';

    }
  }

</script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('is_offer').value = 'yes') {
    document.getElementById('offer').innerText = '<div class="form-group m-form__group row"> <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">* Discount::</label> <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9"> <div id="asd"></div> </div> </div>';

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">

  <select class="form-control m-input" name="is_offer" id="is_offer" onclick="myFunction()" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>--Choose--</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>

</div>


<div id="offer"></div>
```

Comment: What errors (if any) do you get in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition statement has issues. Use document.getElementById('is_offer').value === 'yes' (triple-equals)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.innerHTML` to set the div not `innerText`. `innerText` assumes all your html data is text and adds it like a text. ,For the yes condition, `=` is used for assignment but we have to compare so `==` is used. And call the  function on `onchange` event not on `click` of the select tag

```js
function myFunction()
        {
           if( document.getElementById('is_offer').value=='yes')
           {
               document.getElementById('offer').innerHTML='<div class="form-group m-form__group row"> <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">* Discount::</label> <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9"> <div id="asd"></div> </div> </div>';

           }
           else
           document.getElementById('offer').innerHTML=''
           
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">

 <select class="form-control m-input" name="is_offer" id="is_offer" onChange="myFunction()" required>
         <option value="" disabled selected >--Choose--</option>
          <option value="yes" >Yes</option>
          <option value="no">No</option>
         </select>

    </div>


 <div id="offer"></div>
```

Comment: Adding: Also put an "else" part in the if, that sets the innerHTML to an empty string "" when the choice made was not "yes". This way the "Discount"-Div will be removed when "no" is selected again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction()
    {
       if (document.getElementById('is_offer').value === 'yes')
       {
           document.getElementById('offer').innerHTML = '<div class="form-group m-form__group row"> <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">* Discount::</label> <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9"> <div id="asd"></div></div></div>';
       }
    }
```

and change `onclick` with `onChange`.

Answer (score 0):

You had 3 issues should be changed.

1. If you want to listen the change of input, you shoule use `onchange` instead of `onclick`.
2. In `if` condition you use assigning variables instead of comparison (use `==` or `===`).
3. It seems you would like to change HTML content. So you should use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

After fixing all of them we have code like this:

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">

    <select class="form-control m-input" name="is_offer" id="is_offer" onchange="myFunction()" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Choose--</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>

</div>


<div id="offer"></div>


<script>
    function myFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById('is_offer').value === 'yes') {
            document.getElementById('offer').innerHTML = '<div class="form-group m-form__group row"> <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">* Discount::</label> <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9"> <div id="asd"></div> </div> </div>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use the `onchange` event on the select tag. Also, you should use `===` to compare the value with `yes` or `no`, not just `=` whish is an assignment.

By using a template and cloning it, you don't have to mix your JavaScript with HTML code, you just have to fetch the template, clone it and append it to your `div`.

Do not query the document to find your select in your handler, you have access to it via the `event.target` object, which you get access to as argument to your handler.

Also, don't forget to erase the discount when you select `no`.

```js
function onSelect(event) {
    const offer = document.getElementById('offer'); 
    offer.innerHTML = '';
    
    if (event.target.value === 'yes') {
      const tpl = document.getElementById('discount-tpl');
      const clone = document.importNode(tpl.content, true);
      offer.appendChild(clone);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
  <select class="form-control m-input" name="is_offer" id="is_offer" onchange="onSelect(event)" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected >--Choose--</option>
    <option value="yes" >Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="offer"></div>

<template id="discount-tpl">
  <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">* Discount::</label>
    <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9">
      <div id="asd"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```